# How to redirect from one module to another module in zend2

Tags: zend-framework2, redirect

I have done this into my constructor

```
 $acl = new Acl();
    $acl->addRole(new Role('guest'))
    ->addRole(new Role('user'))
    ->addRole(new Role('admin'));

    $acl->addResource(new Resource('login'));
    $acl->addResource(new Resource('forgotpassowrdAction'));

    $acl->deny('user','login');
    $acl->deny('guest', 'login');
    $acl->deny('guest', 'forgotpassowrdAction');
    $access=$acl->isAllowed('guest', 'login') ? "Allowed" : "Denied";
    if($access=='Denied'){
        $res=new Request();
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute("forgotpassowrdAction");
    }
```

I want to redirect to my application Module in IndexController.php in AccessDeniedAction(). Please let me know how I can do It.
when I have Used

```
Url plugin requires that controller event compose a router; none found
```

this is the error.
Please help me, I just want to implement ACL in User Controller.

Comment: "forgotpassowrdAction" does not look like a indexed route to me. Please check your module.config and redirect to a defined route. Plus what do you mean with you have done this inside a constructor. Which one?